# QAxObject is not creating slots signals for a COM object

Tags: c++, qt, com

I am using Qt3.3 (and there is no option to upgrade, we are in time, moving away from Qt completely)

When I create a WebBrowser object with:

```
m_lpWebBrowser  = new QAxWidget(this, "ActiveX WebBrowser Plugin");
m_lpWebBrowser->setControl("{8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2}");
```

signals are created for every Event from the browser (55 in total)

However if I respond to a DocumentCompleted event with:

```
pCtrl->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowser2, (void**)&brws);
brws->get_Document((IDispatch**)&doc);
m_pDocument = new QAxObject(doc, this, "Document");
```

where pCtrl is the IDispatch returned by the event I get an object which is clearly an HTMLDocument (I can queryInterface for any of the IHTMLDocument(n) interfaces) but it only has three signals:

```
signal(const QString&,int,void*)
propertyChanged(const QString&)
exception(int,const QString&,const QString&,const QString&)
```

The same problem occurs if I use the more roundabout method of getting an IDispatch* for the document and constructing an QAxObject* from it.

In both cases it is clear that setControl is never called for the new QAxObject and this seems to be necessary to construct the signals.
The specific interface that I need to access is IHTMLDocumentEvents.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't have much experience with QAxObject, but is this question related to yours - http://www.qtforum.org/article/23962/connecting-from-a-qaxobject-event-signal.html? OP there is on Qt3 as well, and he says his problem appears when constructing a QAxObject from inside an event. But I'm not sure it's entirely the same problem.

Comment: Why move away from Qt? Anyway, specific shortcoming with COM object signals solution is here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/35085/handle-activex-events-with-custom-enum-parameters I am not giving that as an answer as long as it works for me with Qt 5.x and unsure about Qt 3.x.

Comment: @sashoalm It's not the same issue, I don't have any signals created on the object let alone dysfunctional ones.  The suggestion to move the object construction out of the event handler seemed relevant but unfortunately this doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to resolve the question of why this didn't work but it turn out that writing your own event sink isn't quite as daunting as it seems.  QAxEventSink provides a simple example and demonstrates that you actually only need to implement the Invoke function.